# Android top padding between TextInputLayout and TextInputEditText when a hint is present

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

Can't figure it out where this strange padding is growing from.

The padding that I'm talking to can be seen on this screenshot

[image]

Input text layout:

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    android:id="@+id/name_input_field"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/sixteen_dp_margin"
    android:elevation="16dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/view_corner_radius"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/recycler_view">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/filledPlantName"
        style="@style/InputTextField"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/plant_name">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/name_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences"
            android:singleLine="true" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

Style:

```
<style name="InputTextField" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
    <item name="boxBackgroundColor">@color/main_background</item>
    <item name="boxCornerRadiusTopStart">@dimen/16dp</item>
    <item name="boxCornerRadiusTopEnd">@dimen/16dp</item>
    <item name="boxCornerRadiusBottomStart">@dimen/16dp</item>
    <item name="boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd">@dimen/16dp</item>
    <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/accent_color</item>
    <item name="hintTextColor">@color/accent_color</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

What I'm trying to do is to add elevation to input text by wrapping it with cardView. But this weird padding is messing with it.

That is the result of this padding, space between
[image]

I guess it's my hint's fault, because when I add this line to my theme:

`<item name="hintEnabled">false</item>`

everything is okay, but there is no hint now and I need it!

How can I eliminate this extra padding while preserving the hint that I need?

P.S.
I should mention that this is outlined box and should become orange when text is entered. I want to preserve this look and just add a shadow around it...

Looks like this when text is entered:
[image: outlinedbox when pressed]

Answer (score 1):

try it:

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
android:id="@+id/name_input_field"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/sixteen_dp_margin"
android:elevation="16dp"
app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/view_corner_radius"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/recycler_view">

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/filledPlantName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/plant_name"
android:background="@color/white">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/name_edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences"
 style="@style/InputTextField"
        android:singleLine="true" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>` add the attribute

```
app:boxBackgroundMode="filled"
```

Comment: Yep, this removes the top margin but also clips desired outline look =(

Screenshot: https://drive.google.com/file/d/10uZsT-5JJrz-EF982FE2I7OIOzxuP3N1/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Inputlayout set background="@null"

Comment: If you meen android:background="@null", it's changing nothing...